# How do I use ansible_become_password on different target in the same playbook

Tags: shell, ansible, passwords, sudo, su

My playbook has a task to copy a file from the local box to the remote box and the last task has to use sudo to root. I am not getting it to work.

In my inventory I am trying to use I am just trying to get it to work then I can lock it down with ansible vault. I just need to see it work first.

```
[logserver]
mylogserver ansible_ssh_user=myuser ansible_become_password=mypassword
```

In my playbook the last task using the -host param to do the work on the remote box, earlier task copies file to remote server but then I add a remote host to get the work done.

```
# Cat file and append destination file 
- name: cat files to destination file
  hosts: mylogserver
  gather_facts: no
  become_exe: "sudo su - root"
  tasks: 
  - name: cat contents and append to destination file
    shell: 
      cmd: /usr/bin/cat /var/tmp/test_file.txt >> /etc/some/target_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
test_11 ansible_ssh_user=User1 ansible_become_password=mypassword

[logserver]
test_11
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: logserver
  gather_facts: false
  become_method: su
  become_exe: sudo su
  become_user: root
  become_flags: -l
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      become: true
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

work as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

PLAY [logserver] ******************************************************************************

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: root

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Notes:

- Configuration of the method, e.g. *`become_method: su`*, is missing. See [DEFAULT_BECOME_METHOD](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become-method). The default is 'sudo'. For details see [Using Become Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/become.html#using-become-plugins)
- See details of the plugin from the command line *`shell> ansible-doc -t become su`*
- Use *become_flags* to specify options to pass to su, e.g. *`become_flags: -l`*
- Use *become_user* to specify the user you 'become' to execute the task, e.g. *`become_user: root`*. This example is redundant. 'root' is the default
- Specify *`become: true`* if the task shall use the configured escalation. The default is 'false'. See [DEFAULT_BECOME](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become)
- Configure sudoers, e.g.

```yaml
    - command: grep User1 /usr/local/etc/sudoers
      become: true
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: User1 ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

---

**Encrypt the password**

1. Remove the password from inventory *hosts* and put it into a file, e.g. in *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
test_11 ansible_ssh_user=User1

[logserver]
test_11
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/test_11/ansible_become_password.yml 
ansible_become_password: mypassword
```

2. Encrypt the password

```sh
shell> ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/test_11/ansible_become_password.yml 
Encryption successful
```

```sh
shell> cat host_vars/test_11/ansible_become_password.yml
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
35646364306161623262653632393833323662633738323639353539666231373165646238636236
3462386536666463323136396131326333636365663264350a383839333536313937353637373765
...
```

3. Test the playbook

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

PLAY [logserver] ******************************************************************************

TASK [command] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: root

...
```

Comment: Wow that did work but now I have a permission denied. I am really trying to append the snmptrapd.conf file but I get  permission denied here is the ls -al file permissions

-rw-------  1 root root 1500 Apr 14 20:12 /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf